# Are there infinitely many polynomials crossing through a finite amount of points?

Tags: functions, polynomials

If I have $3$ $(x,y)$ points, say $(2,3)$, $(8,17)$ and $(20,25)$, how many polynomials are there that pass through those $3$ points? Infinitely many or a finite amount? What if I have $n$ arbitrary points? How many (polynomial) functions pass through those $n$ $(x,y)$ points? My guess is infinitely many, with every different polynomial of a varying degree. Please correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try discussing on Quotient Matrix of systems of linear equations which is a Vandermonde matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can fit a cubic polynomial to four points, you could add the point $(0,r)$ to your list and get one polynomial of degree at most three for each $r$. So you can get an infinite number of polynomials of degree $3$ (excluding any of lower degree).

---

You can fit a polynomial of degree at most $n-1$ to $n$ points. Choose $m$ additional values of $x$ - then any polynomial of degree at most $n-1+m$ passing through the original $n$ points will have values for those $m$ values of $x_i$.

Conversely for any choice of $y_i$ we can fit a polynomial of degree at most $n+m-1$ to the original $n$ points plus the additional $m$ points $(x_i,y_i)$ so we can parametrise the polynomials of degree $n+m-1$ through the original $n$ points by the $m$ values of $y_i$.

Answer (score 4):

Here are infinitely many answers to your first problem:
$$3\Bigl(\frac{x-8}{-6}\Bigr)^a\Bigl(\frac{x-20}{-18}\Bigr)^b
  +17\Bigl(\frac{x-2}{6}\Bigr)^c\Bigl(\frac{x-20}{-12}\Bigr)^d
  +25\Bigl(\frac{x-2}{18}\Bigr)^e\Bigl(\frac{x-8}{12}\Bigr)^f\ ,$$
where $a,b,c,d,e,f$ are positive integers.  You should be able to do the generalisation in a similar way.